# Basic VBA - Looping and Inputbox

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I need help finishing some pretty basic VBA coding.

So far I have been able to have random numbers between 1 and 100 into a certain range (A1:J10) and have the values read from the worksheet and store them in a 2-dimensional array of Integer.

However, I need help with:

1. Looping through the values in the array and count the number of values that are greater than a value specified by the user (thought an `InputBox` while remembering to convert the values from a string to a interger, also needing to use an if statment to makesure numbers are between 1 and 100). The results need to be displayed in a message box
2. Then it needs to loop through all values in the range and shade the cells with values larger than the specified number in blue.

Can anybody help? This is what I have so far

```
Sub numrange()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:J10")
    r.Formula = "=randbetween(1,100)"

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    arr = Range("A1:J10").Value
    ReDim arrint(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), _
        LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)) As Integer
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arrint(i, j) = arr(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you're doing this specifically as an exercise to learn VBA, you'd be better off doing the second part with conditional formatting.

Comment: I am new to VBA, it's for a class. I don't know what conditional formatting is I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter solution without array:

```
Sub numrange()
  Dim r As Range, count As Integer, number As Variant
  Set r = Range("A1:J10")

  r.Formula = "=randbetween(1,100)"
  r.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

  count = 0
  number = InputBox("Insert number between 1 and 100")
  If number >= 1 And number <= 100 Then
    For Each cell In r
      If cell > CInt(number) Then
        count = count + 1
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
      End If
    Next
    MsgBox count & " numbers are greather than " & number
  Else
    MsgBox "Not a valid number"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've done and successfully implemented what you've thought, try:

**Edit1:** Adding InputBox

```
Sub marine()

    Dim r As Range, iCnt As Integer
    Dim arr, iVal
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, myprompt As String

    Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1:J10") '/* change Sheet1 to your actual sheet */
    r.Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)"
    r.Interior.Color = xlNone '/* remove existing formatting */

    arr = r.Value2
    myprompt = "Please enter numbers between 1 to 100."
    Do
        iVal = InputBox(myprompt, "Count and color")
        myprompt = "You entered an invalid number." & vbNewLine & _
                   "Please enter number between 1 and 100 only."
        If iVal = "" Then Exit Sub '/* if user cancels */
        If Not IsNumeric(iVal) Then
            myprompt = "Invalid entry, numeric value expected." & vbNewLine & _
                       "Please enter numbers between 1 and 100."
        End If
    Loop Until iVal >= 1 And iVal <= 100

    iCnt = 0
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(i, j) > CInt(iVal) Then
                iCnt = iCnt + 1
                r.Item(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "Total of " & iCnt & " number(s) greater than " & iVal

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added that to my code, but I am unsure where to put the input box (where you input a value for it to be highlighted when its greater than the number specified). Right now it is just highlighting everything blue without an input box option.

Comment: @MeganStarbuck Yeah, I thought you can handle that. See updates.

Comment: I don't know why I got a downvote :) but the good thing is it helps the OP.